# swift - how to display two different images in a custom made view cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have three imagesviews in my view cell they currently all display the same image i would like to know how to make each image a seperate image, maybe something like 
if image = imagebanana display image of banana else if image = imageapple display image of apple,   as at the moment all images in each individual cell are banana , banana, banana  and i wanted to have banana, apple , pear in the one cell?

```
struct cellData {

let cell: Int!
let text: String!
let image: UIImage!   
}



class HomepageVC2JAREDTutorial: UITableViewController {


var arrayofCellData = [cellData]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    arrayofCellData = [cellData(cell : 1, text : "tom",image : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tom3")),cellData(cell : 2, text : "denis",image : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "denis2")),cellData(cell : 1, text : "mark",image : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mark1")),]



}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arrayofCellData.count
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    if arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].cell == 1{


        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("XibCustomCellJared", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! XibCustomCellJared

        cell.ProfilePictureImageView.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.MoreOptionsImageView.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.AccountTypeImageView.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.DisplayNameLabel.text = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].text
        cell.StatusSubtitleLabel.text = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].text

        return cell


    }else if arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].cell == 2{


        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Xib2CustomCellJared", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Xib2CustomCellJared

        cell.ProfilePictureImageView.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.MoreOptionsImageView.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.AccountTypeImageView.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.DisplayNameLabel.text = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].text
        cell.StatusSubtitleLabel.text = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].text

        return cell

    }else{




            let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("XibCustomCellJared", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! XibCustomCellJared

            cell.ProfilePictureImageView.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.MoreOptionsImageView.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.AccountTypeImageView.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.DisplayNameLabel.text = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].text
            cell.StatusSubtitleLabel.text = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].text

            return cell



        }

}
```

Comment: you need to add 3 different images in each object if you want to show different images in each cell imageviews.

Comment: I really still do not understand the difficulty you are having ... Why do not you use 3 pictures in your struct cellData
One for each imageview?

Comment: thanks @ClaudioCastro just from saying that i understand now! beautiful

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I missed the title where you said you made a custom made view cell. Either way, the approach below would probably work for you if you're using storyboards.

Have you created a *Table View Cell* specifically for your tableview? I think you might be able to accomplish what you're going for more easily that way.

In the *Table View Cell* (identified as a prototype cell in your tableview), you can create the three separate image views and give each one a unique identifier (tag) as shown in the image below. When you create a table view cell, you have to give the view cell a unique identifier as well.

**Table View Cell identifier**
[image]

**Tag identifier for specific image view (can be any int)**
[image]

Once you have your table view cell identified and you give your image views tag numbers, we can get to some code.

Inside of your `cellForRowAt indexPath` function, you would create code that is similar to what is shown below:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //the .dequeReusableCell method creates the instance for the table
    //view cell you created in the storyboard. Make sure you copy the 
    //identifier exactly as it appears in the storyboard.    

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "whateverCellIdentifierYouChoose", for: indexPath)

    //The .viewWithTag method creates the instance for the objects
    //you created in the table view cell. Copy the tag number
    //exactly as you specified it in the storyboard. 

    let bananaImage = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    let appleImage = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
    let pearImage = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView

    //code below specifies the image you are going to populate
    //each UIImageView with

    bananaImage.image = UIImage(named: "banana")
    appleImage.image = UIImage(named: "apple")
    pearImage.image = UIImage(named: "pear")

    return cell
}
```

Try this and see if it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You create data for cell in your model.
 Sample:

```
 cellData{
   var image1:UIImage; // apple
   var image2:UIImage; //pear
   var image3:UIImage; // banana
   var text:String;
   ....
}
```

and in `cellforrowatindexpath` get data:

```
let data = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row] as! cellData  
cell.ProfilePictureImageView.image = data.image1  
cell.ProfilePictureImageView.image = data.image1  
cell.ProfilePictureImageView.image = data.image1
```